# Onclick function not working on inserted HTML

Tags: jquery

Im just new to jquery and while doing experimentations on jquery I encountered this problem -> It can insert the html to the div but the click function in not working on the inserted html. Anyone knows why? thanks in advance

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$("#insertTest").click(function(){
$("#testDiv").html($("#testDiv").html() + '<p><a href="#" class="testClick">Click  Me</a></p>');
});

$(".testClick").click(function(){
alert('Ahoy');
});

});

<a href="#" id="insertTest">Click to Insert</a>
<div id="testDiv">
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `.on()` method http://api.jquery.com/on/, `.live()` is deprecated as of 1.7, so to ensure future compatibility, use `on()` instead of `live()`

http://api.jquery.com/live/

> As of jQuery 1.7, the .live() method is deprecated. Use .on() to
>   attach event handlers. Users of older versions of jQuery should use
>   .delegate() in preference to .live().

```
$('.testClick').on('click', function(){
    alert('Ahoy');
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the method `live()`

```
$('.testClick').live('click', function(){
    alert('Ahoy');
});
```

**Edit: to support jQuery 1.7+ standards, use `.on()` instead of `.live()`**

Comment: As of jQuery 1.7 .live() has been deprecated in favor of .on().

Comment: I've trie the **.live** and it works, thanks for all the feedback guys, I really appreaciated it, thanks again

Answer (score 0):

You could use `.live`, but it is deprecated, use [.on](http://api.jquery.com/on/) instead.
And you you could use `.append` for insert the html.

```
$("#insertTest").click(function () {
    $("#testDiv").append('<p><a href="#" class="testClick">Click  Me</a></p>');
});

$("#testDiv").on('click', '.testClick', function () {
    alert('Ahoy');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

here you go: http://jsfiddle.net/Hc7Cc/26/

o well I can see you have enough hint:

here is the working jsfiddle

working demo: http://jsfiddle.net/Hc7Cc/26/

Cheers